# Odd answer for greedy.c CS50/ C-Language

Tags: c, cs50

```
int main(void)
{
double change;
int x = 0;

// loops everytime user inputs invalid #//

do 
{
  printf("How much change is owed? \n");
  change = get_float();    
}
while(change < 0);


//declaring i for change in int, rounds to int from float//
int i = roundf(change * 100);


while (i >= 25){
x++;
i -= 25;
}

while (i >= 10){
x++;
i -= 10;
}

while(i >= 5){
x++;
i -= 5;
}

while(i >= 1){
x++;
i -= 1;
}

//prints x; total amt of coins used//
printf("%x\n", x);

return 0;
```

Alright so, when I interact with this, I type in 1, and I get 4. Which is correct.

If I type in 2, I get 8; So far so good..

**When I type in 3 however, I get the letter c(?) as an answer.** I've been stuck with this problem for a little while now, as well as searching google, but to no avail have I found something similar to this.

I've been told that I'm missing braces in my while loops, so I added those. But it doesn't change anything.

1). Is there something I could do to not get the letter c as the amt of coins?

**I'd greatly appreciate it if I get some pointers, instead of being directly told the answer; I want to understand what it is I'm doing. Thanks!**

Comment: What do you think that %x means? The problem is 'base'-ic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C` is hexadecimal for `12`, therefore it is returning the value as expected, given your `printf()` statement..  Consider changing the `%x` (which tells it to print using hexadecimal) to `%d` (normal decimal) and I believe you will get the value you are expecting:

```
printf("%x\n", x);
```

to

```
printf("%d\n", x);
```

This mistake is at such a basic level that it is hard not to just give you the answer here - it literally is changing a single character in your source to fix the issue.

Comment: I had no idea C was that explicit.

Comment: *All* computer languages are that explicit. Well, except Prolog, how that works under the covers is *anybody's* guess :-)

Comment: @HurielValverde this kind of behaviour is standard in most systems programming languages, or any language featuring formatted printing. You'll see the same thing in Java, C#, Go, Rust, and even Bash. As for Prolog, it's binary tree magic all the way down.